# (Beamer) Dim equation block and write text on it

Tags: beamer, equations, transparency

I want to dim a block of equations in my slide and put a skull symbol on it (to indicate that those steps are wrong). I tried using `alt`, but that doesn't do the right thing and instead, the word "alt" shows up on the slide with some strange symbol.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}
%%%%%%%%%



\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}         


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Generalizing from one case to another}
Some stuff goes here: $g(x)= g_1(x) = g_2(x) \leq g_3(x)$

\pause
Analogous attempt: 
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= f_1(x)\\
        &= f_2(x)\\
        &\leq f_3(x)
\end{align*}
\pause
The above stuff is wrong, since the final inequality doesn't hold unless some conditions are met. 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Specifically, I'd like to dim the `align` block above, right after the final sentence of the slide appears, and put a skull above it. (if skull isn't possible, a text saying, "Wrong") is also okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to get something of that sort.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,overlay-beamer-styles,tikzmark}
\usepackage{skull}


\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}         


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Generalizing from one case to another}
Some stuff goes here: $g(x)= g_1(x) = g_2(x) \leq g_3(x)$

\pause
Analogous attempt: 
\begin{align*}
\tikzmarknode{f}{f}(x) &= f_1(x)\\
        &= f_2(x)\\
        &\leq \tikzmarknode{f3}{f_3(x)}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \only<3->{\node[fill=white,fill opacity=0.5,text opacity=0.8,
        fit=(f) (f3),align=center]      {~\\\scalebox{3}{$\skull$}};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{align*}
\pause
The above stuff is wrong, since the final inequality doesn't hold unless some conditions are met. 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you help me understand when I should use ```overlay``` and when ```remember picture```? I tried doing so by removing them one by one, but both have the same effect, of putting the skull in an unpredictable spot (at least unpredictable in my view). Further, can we use ```\tikzmarknode``` to mark any type of LaTeX element? For instance, a group of theorems? Thank you for your answer!!

Comment: @lazulikid `remember picture` is a key that allows us to use the nodes defined in another picture in the current picture. `overlay` means that the picture does not have a bounding box, and can be moved freely. We need both keys here because we need access to the nodes defined in the `\tikzmarknode`s, and we want to add the `tikzpicture` on top of the equation.